# Preventing program execution with batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, process

I am running one batch file in loop continuously. While this `.bat` file is running it should not allow one particular executable to run.

How can this be achieved? Can that particular executable be watched, or can it be detected if has not been clicked, or - if clicked - it should be disallowed from running.

Ultimately, `.bat` file and particular executable should not run at same time- **if `.bat` file is running it should not executable to run**.

Comment: What OS are you running? - Depending on what version of Windows (7, 8, 8.1, Server 2008, Server 2012 etc.) you can use either Software Restriction Policies or AppLocker - but they need to be at least Enterprise or Ultimate

Comment: Can you modify the executable? Or is it something supplied as a binary only by a third party? Do you need to actually prevent the program running, or would it be acceptable to replace the entry on the start menu with a program that checks if your batch file is running and only runs the real program if it isn't?

Comment: @big chris, i am running windows 7.

Comment: @david, no i cant modify the exe. yes i need to prevent program from running. no, i want it to be checked only by batch file

Comment: Which version? My answer (well, part of it) only works on enterprise or Ultimate...

Comment: @big chris, your answer is acceptable. i wanted to run batch file in the loop and wanted this batch file to prevent other xyz.exe from starting if someone clicks that exe by mistake. i dont want .exe file to be run while batch file is in the loop.

Comment: If the loop is in the middle of processing and someone runs the unwanted exe (and the loop doesn't notice) then you will have your problem. You need a way to either prevent the programming running at all or allow some margin to kill the process if it's started without causing your problem. Both are difficult: 1) how critical the loop is that your exe doesn't run and b) the version of Windows you run.

Comment: There's always the dirty hack of renaming the .exe file while the .bat is running.

Comment: How about: Have the batch file rename the EXE first, do it's thing, then rename the EXE back at the end if the batch.

Comment: @ big chris thnks,

Comment: @ qasdfdsaq, @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes that can be done too thx..:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a batch file in a continuous loop will not be able to prevent an application from starting. it can be used to see if an application is already running and then kill it. However, if the program you don't want to start starts after your "kill" call (i.e. it runs during your processing portion of your script) then there is no way to monitor this.

You could write a script that loops continuously and only kills the unwanted process - but this is wasteful on processor cycles.

You could write a service that watches for the program to start and then kills it - but you would need, say, Visual Studio (or alternative) and the knowledge to write a Windows Service...

Alternatively, if you have Windows 7 (or higher) Enterprise or Ultimate you could look into using **Software Restriction Policies** or **AppLocker**.